# How to apply class decorator at base of all decorators on methods

Tags: python, python-decorators

I am using this way of decorating all methods

```
import inspect

def decallmethods(decorator, prefix='test_'):
  def dectheclass(cls):
    for name, m in inspect.getmembers(cls, inspect.ismethod):
      if name.startswith(prefix):
        setattr(cls, name, decorator(m))
    return cls
  return dectheclass


@decallmethods(login_testuser)
class TestCase(object):
    def setUp(self):
        pass

    def test_1(self):
        print "test_1()"

    def test_2(self):
        print "test_2()"
```

This is working but it applies at the top , if i have other decorators.

I mean

Now the result is

```
@login_testuser
@other
def test_2(self):
    print "test_2()"
```

But i want

```
@other
@login_testuser
def test_2(self):
    print "test_2()"
```

Comment: You might want to think about how you might turn the code from `test_2 = login_testuser(other(test_2))` into `test_2 = other(login_testuser(test_2))`.  My suggestion is that you think of another method that avoids the `other` decorator on your test. While there are ways to manipulate the closures formed by the decorators but it will be quite messy.

Comment: @metatoaster . Can you give me some idea how can i do that in closures . I have many methods so it won't be possible to duplicate that.

Comment: I would recommend you edit the title to reflect the true intent of what you are doing, such as "inject a decorator into its original function that was already decorated". or something to this effect.  This turned out to be way harder than I thought.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is most certainly a **bad** idea, but what you want to do can be done in some extent, and this is going to take a lot of time to explain.  First off, rather than thinking of decorators as a syntax sugar, think of them as what they really are: a function (that is a closure) with a function that exist inside it.  Now this is out of the way, supposed we have a function:

```
def operation(a, b):
    print('doing operation')
    return a + b
```

Simply it will do this

```
>>> hi = operation('hello', 'world')
doing operation
>>> print(hi)
helloworld
```

Now define a decorator that prints something before and after calling its inner function (equivalent to the `other` decorator that you want to decorator later):

```
def other(f):  
    def other_inner(*a, **kw):
        print('other start')
        result = f(*a, **kw)
        print('other finish')
        return result
    return other_inner
```

With that, build a new function and decorator

```
@other
def o_operation(a, b):
    print('doing operation')
    return a + b
```

Remembering, this is basically equivalent to `o_operation = other(operation)`

Run this to ensure it works:

```
>>> r2 = o_operation('some', 'inner')
other start
doing operation
other finish
>>> print(r2)
someinner
```

Finally, the final decorator you want to call immediately before `operation` but not `d_operation`, but with your existing code it results in this:

```
def inject(f):
    def injected(*a, **kw):
        print('inject start')
        result = f(*a, **kw)
        print('inject finish')
        return result
    return injected

@inject
@other
def i_o_operation(a, b):
    print('doing operation')
    return a + b
```

Run the above:

```
>>> i_o_operation('hello', 'foo')
inject start
other start
doing operation
other finish
inject finish
'hellofoo'
```

As mentioned decorators are really closures and hence that's why it's possible to have items inside that are effectively instanced inside.  You can reach them by going through the `__closure__` attribute:

```
>>> i_o_operation.__closure__
(<cell at 0x7fc0eabd1fd8: function object at 0x7fc0eabce7d0>,)
>>> i_o_operation.__closure__[0].cell_contents
<function other_inner at 0x7fc0eabce7d0>
>>> print(i_o_operation.__closure__[0].cell_contents('a', 'b'))
other start
doing operation
other finish
ab
```

See how this effectively calls the function inside the `injected` closure directly, as if that got unwrapped.  What if that closure can be replaced with the one that did the injection?  For all of our protection, `__closure__` and `cell.cell_contents` are read-only.  What needs to be done is to construct completely new functions with the intended closures by making use of the [`FunctionType`](https://docs.python.org/library/types.html#types.FunctionType) function constructor (found in the [`types`](https://docs.python.org/library/types.html) module)

Back to the problem.  Since what we have now is:

```
i_o_operation = inject(other(operation))
```

And what we want is

```
o_i_operation = other(inject(operation))
```

We effectively have to somehow strip the call to `other` from `i_o_operation` and somehow wrap it around with `inject` to produce `o_i_operation`.  (Dragons follows after the break)

---

First, construct a function that effectively calls `inject(operation)` by taking the closure to level deep (so that `f` will contain just the original `operation` call) but mix it with the code produced by `inject(f)`:

```
i_operation = FunctionType(
    i_o_operation.__code__,
    globals=globals(),
    closure=i_o_operation.__closure__[0].cell_contents.__closure__,
)
```

Since `i_o_operation` is the result of `inject(f)` we can take that code to produce a new function. The `globals` is a formality that's required, and finally take the closure of the nested level, and the first part of the function is produced.  Verify that the `other` is not called.

```
>>> i_operation('test', 'strip')
inject start
doing operation
inject finish
'teststrip'
```

Neat.  However we still want the `other` to be wrapped outside of this to finally produce `o_i_operation`.  We do need to somehow put this new function we produced in a closure, and a way to do this is to create a surrogate function that produce one

```
def closure(f):
    def surrogate(*a, **kw):
        return f(*a, **kw)
    return surrogate
```

And simply use it to construct and extract our closure

```
o_i_operation = FunctionType(
    i_o_operation.__closure__[0].cell_contents.__code__,
    globals=globals(),
    closure=closure(i_operation).__closure__,
)
```

Call this:

```
>>> o_i_operation('job', 'complete')
other start
inject start
doing operation
inject finish
other finish
'jobcomplete'
```

Looks like we finally got what we need.  While this doesn't exactly answer your exact problem, this started down the right track but is already pretty hairy.

---

Now for the actual problem: a function that will ensure a decorator function be the most inner (final) callable before a given original, undecorated function - i.e. for a given `target` and a `f(g(...(callable))`, we want to emulate a result that gives `f(g(...(target(callable))))`.  This is the code:

```
from types import FunctionType

def strip_decorators(f):
    """
    Strip all decorators from f.  Assumes each are functions with a
    closure with a first cell being the target function.
    """

    # list of not the actual decorator, but the returned functions
    decorators = []
    while f.__closure__:
        # Assume first item is the target method
        decorators.append(f)
        f = f.__closure__[0].cell_contents
    return decorators, f

def inject_decorator(decorator, f):
    """
    Inject a decorator to the most inner function within the stack of
    closures in `f`.
    """

    def closure(f):
        def surrogate(*a, **kw):
            return f(*a, **kw)
        return surrogate

    decorators, target_f = strip_decorators(f)
    result = decorator(target_f)

    while decorators:
        # pop out the last one in
        decorator = decorators.pop()
        result = FunctionType(
            decorator.__code__,
            globals=globals(),
            closure=closure(result).__closure__,
        )

    return result
```

To test this, we use a typical example use-case - html tags.

```
def italics(f):
    def i(s):
        return '<i>' + f(s) + '</i>'
    return i

def bold(f):
    def b(s):
        return '<b>' + f(s) + '</b>'
    return b

def underline(f):
    def u(s):
        return '<u>' + f(s) + '</u>'
    return u

@italics
@bold
def hi(s):
    return s
```

Running the test.

```
>>> hi('hello')
'<i><b>hello</b></i>'
```

Our target is to inject the `underline` decorator (specifically the `u(hi)` callable) into the most inner closure.  This can be done like so, with the function we have defined above:

```
>>> hi_u = inject_decorator(underline, hi)
>>> hi_u('hello')
'<i><b><u>hello</u></b></i>'
```

Works with undecorated functions:

```
>>> def pp(s):
...     return s 
... 
>>> pp_b = inject_decorator(bold, pp)
>>> pp_b('hello')
'<b>hello</b>'
```

A major assumption was made for this first-cut version of the rewriter, which is that all decorators in the chain only have a closure length of one, that one element being the function being decorated with.  Take this decorator for instance:

```
def prefix(p):
    def decorator(f):
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):
            new_args = [p + a for a in args]
            return f(*new_args, **kwargs)
        return inner
    return decorator
```

Example usage:

```
>>> @prefix('++')
... def prefix_hi(s):
...     return s
... 
>>> prefix_hi('test')
'++test'
```

Now try to inject a `bold` decorator like so:

```
>>> prefix_hi_bold = inject_decorator(bold, prefix_hi)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 18, in inject_decorator
ValueError: inner requires closure of length 2, not 1
```

This is simply because the closure formed by `decorator` within `prefix` has two elements, one being the prefix string `p` and the second being the actual function, and `inner` being nested inside that expects both those to be present inside its closure.  Resolving that will require more code to analyse and reconstruct the details.

---

Anyway, this explanation took quite a bit of time and words, so I hope you understand this and maybe get you started on the actual right track.

If you want to turn `inject_decorator` into a decorator, and/or mix it into your class decorator, best of luck, most of the hard work is already done.

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining , i got that :)