# How Can I Pass args in Class Decorators in Python?

Tags: python, decorator

I am using this code in Python to apply decorator to all methods of class:

```
import inspect

def decallmethods(decorator, prefix='test_'):
  def dectheclass(cls):
    for name, m in inspect.getmembers(cls, inspect.ismethod):
      if name.startswith(prefix):
        setattr(cls, name, decorator(m))
    return cls
  return dectheclass


@decallmethods(login_testuser)
class TestCase(object):
    def setUp(self):
        pass

    def test_1(self):
        print "test_1()"

    def test_2(self):
        print "test_2()"
```

This works fine. But, I want to pass some `kwargs` to decorator which I want to apply.

So, I want something like:

```
@decallmethods(login_testuser, data="TEST") on class
```

and the decorator it applies to methods becomes:

```
@login_testuser(data="TEST")
```

Comment: Why don't you just login the test user in the `setUp` method (and use `unittest`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you constructed this would mean that your `decorator` argument to `decallmethods` becomes a decorator factory (constructor) much like `decallmethods` return a class decorator.  Provided you got that, you just simply need to change the call

```
setattr(cls, name, decorator(m))
```

To

```
setattr(cls, name, decorator(data="TEST")(m))
```

For a static implementation.  To make this dynamic you also need to redefine `decallmethods` to take in the `data` argument

```
def decallmethods(decorator, prefix='test_', data='TEST'):
...
        setattr(cls, name, decorator(data=data)(m))
```

(Also, recall [the time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33249515/how-to-apply-class-decorator-at-base-of-all-decorators-on-methods/33254457#33254457) when I pointed out to you that decorators are simply functions that takes a function to return a new function, that in your case it the call is `test_method = login_testuser(data="TEST")(test_method)` and when it is put this way, reproduction is trivial.)

Naturally, this assumes the function `decorator` will be able to consume the `data` argument and if you pass in decorators that are not decorator factories or functions that do not expect this argument an exception will occur.

Comment: Thanks agian for helping me :). Sorry to confuse but this code is just the sample i copied from somewhere to show what i want to achive . but my code was different. Its not related to unit test . That was just sample code to show what i am looking for

Comment: Ah, you're welcome.  Still, do note the warnings and caveats I mentioned in the answer, they may bite ferociously if care is not taken.